# How do I access the Collection Values within a Flow that are the result of an Apex Action Output value?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, invocablevariable

Hi I've added an Apex Action element to my flow which includes an output value. The Apex Action only returns one record but I understand it has to be returned as a nested list. The output value is a `List<List<sObject>>` and I'm storing it in a Record Collection Variable of the same sObject type.

I need to use the output value later on in the flow and I'm not too sure how to access the value. I've tried looping through the returned collection and assigning the values to a single record variable which didn't work. I've also tried assigning the record collection to another record collection and looping through that, which also didn't work.

I have also tried returning just a `List<sObject>` and storing it in a single record variable which also didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I used the equal count operator to confirm the collection was succesfully returning a value. I've tried several ways to access the values in the returned 'PayableInvoiceRecordCollection' including:

- Looping through the collection and assigning the values of each iteration to a record single variable of the same sObject type
- Assigning the collection to another collection and then doing the above, looping through the collection and assigning the values of each iteration to a record single variable of the same sObject type
- I have also tried returning a single list `List<sObject>` and assigning that to a record single variable of the same sObject type

[image]

The apex code is as follows:

```
public without sharing class One_CreatePayableInvoice {
    public class InputVars {
        @InvocableVariable public string InvoiceAccount;
        @InvocableVariable public string JournalCompany;
        @InvocableVariable public string InvoiceSupplierNumber;
        @InvocableVariable public string InvoiceCurrency;
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>> createInvoices(List<InputVars> Inputs){
        List<List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>> OuterList = new List<List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>>();
        List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c> PayableInvoiceList = new List<c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c>();
        c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c PayableInvoice = new c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c(c2g__Account__c = Inputs[0].InvoiceAccount, c2g__AccountInvoiceNumber__c = Inputs[0].InvoiceSupplierNumber, CurrencyIsoCode = Inputs[0].InvoiceCurrency);
        PayableInvoiceList.add(PayableInvoice);
        OuterList.add(PayableInvoiceList);
        insert PayableInvoiceList;
        return OuterList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/361660/edit) your question to include the pertinent parts of your Apex class and invocable method code. (Use the supplied code formatting by putting triple backticks (```) before and after your swaths of code.) What you refer to as a "nested List" might be interpreted differently by different readers. Also, is the Apex code created by and/or editable by you, or are you only able to call it?

Comment: Hi @Moonpie, I've amended my post with the InvocableMethod code and yes the code is written by me. The insert does work provided I don't try reference the Output Value

Comment: the invocable apex receives a list of inputs representing all the flow interviews in the transaction (1 input per interview) and returns a list of results that Flow will implicitly distribute 1 result to each flow interview.  That is, the invocable apex is bulkified but SFDC takes care of marshaling each flow interview's inputs and unmarshaling the invocable's outputs

Comment: so @cropredy am I correct in thinking the output value needs to be a nested List, ```List<List<sObject>>```?

Comment: only if the flow is expecting the result as a collection variable

Comment: @cropredy The flow is expecting it as a collection variable but I can't reference the values within the collection which is what I need. I have also tried changing the InvocableMethod to return a ```List<sObject>``` and changed the flow to expect a single record variable. Both of which don't work for me.

Comment: you should use [edit] and post entire invocable including definition of `InputVars` and also show the apex action in the Flow with the inputs and output variables

Comment: I was thinking you doing your `insert` after adding your records to your `OuterList` might be an issue. So I created a simple version of your Apex in a Playground Org and wrote a simple Flow to call it. I was wrong - it worked in the order that you have it. My guess now is that the issue might be with how you are manipulating your collection of returned records. When you debug your Flow, does your `PayableInvoiceRecordCollection` show that it contains records? If so, please edit your question to add details of what you are trying to do with that collection after it is returned.

Comment: @Moonpie Hi I used the equal count operator to confirm the collection was successfully returning a value which it it. I've added some more information on what I've tried with the collection variable.

Comment: As I stated, my simple sample (I used Account object, not a custom object, and definitely not one within a package or namespace) worked.  Unless it has something to do with the visibility of the records from the Flow context, I honestly don't know what else to suggest. Sorry.